# Saving stats data in MySQL Database for a line graph

Tags: php, mysql, graph, cron

I'm trying to make a pretty line graph to represent the rate of users registering to my site. What would be the best way to fetch and store my sites stat data to a MySQL Database?

I was thinking to use a cron job that would fetch the total amount of users from a seperate table, and subtract the previous total to get the amount of newly registered users. This value would be used for the line graph. To me, it seems like too much, especially if I want to get rate of users on a per-minute basis. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Should I store each day in a separate row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you include the time that users registered in your users table.  You can then perform whatever analysis you like at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a field in table that is upgraded by a cron job (by minute, hour, day and so on), the field stores the status of user, new, old or other status that you have.

As said eggyal, you must also have a field with register date of user